# Call windows explorer “rotate clockwise” operation from a C# application

Tags: c#, windows, image, powershell, rotation

Does anyone know how to find out what is actually being called here? I'd like to automate this with PowerShell or C#.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what's actually called by those context menu items, but you can invoke these verbs via the [`Shell.Application`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/26/use-powershell-to-work-with-windows-explorer.aspx) object:

```
$path = 'C:\path\to\your.jpg'

$folder = Split-Path -Parent $path
$file   = Split-Path -Leaf $path

$app = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'

$app.NameSpace($folder).ParseName($file).Verbs() |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Rotate cloc&kwise' } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.DoIt() }
```

Comment: Thanks...this worked and is exactly what I was looking for!